# Groovy - XmlSlurper - count node

Tags: groovy, counting, xmlslurper

I am a newbee to Groovy, recently I need to count the complexity of a given XML data block.

I figure out a way to determine if the data block is XML formatted or not. But I am not sure how to count all the nodes of the given XML block.

Here is my code:

```
    def invoke(msg)        
    { 
    try {
       contentBody = msg.get("my.message");
       new XmlSlurper().parseText(contentBody);
       Trace.debug("XML is well formed, request body is "  + contentBody);
       return true;
    }

    catch (Exception e){
        Trace.error("Invalid xml, request body is " + contentBody);
            return false;
     }      
     }
```

Many thanks.

Cheers,
Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

new XmlSlurper().parseText(...).depthFirst().size()

Answer (score 1):

So there are 2 things in the question

1) Checking if the xml is valid
2) Counting the number of nodes under a certain Node

Lets say you have a bad formed xml (Note : **>** is missed from  **tag**

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
  <from
    <test>121</test>
     <testing>123</testing>
   </from>
 <heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Then the output is like

```
Mon Oct 01 08:34:54 IST 2018: ERROR: Invalid XML
Mon Oct 01 08:34:54 IST 2018: ERROR: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected character encountered (lex state 10): '<'
```

So here is the code

```
 def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

 try
{
 def xmlHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("RequestName#Request")
 def countofRoot = xmlHolder.getDomNodes("//*").size()
 def countofbelowNodes = xmlHolder.getDomNodes("//*:from/*").size()

  log.info "size of XML is " + countofRoot
  log.info "size of XML is " + countofbelowNodes

   }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   log.error "Invalid XML"
    log.error e
   }
```

When the XML is correct. It gives the below output

[image]

Please note if you give wrong xpath then exception can come due to that also. So its not necessary that its an Invalid XML. But the e i.e exception detail will help you in knowing the problem

i feel easy to use xmlHolder then XMLParser/XMLSlurper